# Secure SQL Server Configuration

Tags: sql-server, security

What configurations should be made to harden SQL Server 2016 by default (scoped to instance configurations)?

We'd like to tighten up security on our SQL Server 2016 instances. As part of that, we planned on restricting access to the following from procedures by members of "public":

1. xp_regaddmultistring
2. xp_regdeletekey
3. xp_regdeletevalue
4. xp_regenumvalues
5. xp_regread
6. xp_regremovemultistring
7. xp_regwrite
8. xp_regenumkeys
9. sp_OACreate
10. sp_OADestroy
11. sp_OAGetErrorInfo
12. sp_OAGetProperty
13. sp_OAMethod
14. sp_OASetProperty
15. sp_OAStop
16. xp_cmdshell
17. xp_availablemedia
18. xp_loginconfig
19. xp_logininfo
20. xp_fixeddrives
21. xp_fileexist
22. xp_getnetname
23. xp_subdirs
24. xp_enumerrorlogs
25. xp_ReadErrorLog
26. xp_EnumGroups
27. xp_LogEvent
28. xp_MsVer
29. xp_sprintf
30. xp_sscanf
31. xp_ServiceControl
32. xp_GrantLogin
33. xp_RevokeLogin
34. xp_instance_regaddmultistring
35. xp_instance_regdeletekey
36. xp_instance_regdeletevalue
37. xp_instance_regenumvalues
38. xp_instance_regread
39. xp_instance_regremovemultistring
40. xp_instance_regwrite

We're revoking access to the following server permissions:

1. VIEW ANY DATABASE

Answer (score 1):

Follow the practice of least-privilege. Use groups and assign users to the groups via AD. From there, you assign individual permissions on each object. This is much more granular than just using db_reader and db_writer. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Also, be aware that when you make changes to objects (e.g., DROP AND RECREATE), then group permissions may be reset.

Some good reading on the topic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authorization-and-permissions-in-sql-server

https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/what-is-least-privilege/